# Perform an svn commit in a remote directory

Tags: svn, command-prompt

Is it possible to `svn commit` (in Windows) to somewhere other than the working directory?

```
C:\Users\someuser>cd "E:\SVN_Releases\DEV" && svn commit  -m 'This is a test.'
svn: E155007: 'C:\Users\someuser\is' is not a working copy
```

I have also tried (with variations):

```
C:\Users\someuser>svn commit "E:\SVN_Releases\DEV" -m 'This is a test.'
svn: E155007: 'C:\Users\someuser\is' is not a working copy
```

Am looking for a one-liner..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change single quotes to double quotes on message part:

```
C:\Users\someuser>svn commit "E:\SVN_Releases\DEV" -m "This is a test."
```

Comment: Hurrah!  Knew it had to be something obvious!!